# Need space after [ICCS] in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Column_name
[ICCS]C54CNWHPEGNPY2V
[ICCS]C6D4007RP26DM3K
```

Row Data

```
row 1 data - [ICCS]C54CNWHPEGNPY2V
row 2 data -[ICCS]C6D4007RP26DM3K
```

Comment: row 1 data -  [ICCS]C54CNWHPEGNPY2V

Comment: row 2 data -[ICCS]C6D4007RP26DM3K

Comment: Clearly `column_name` should be two columns, a prefix and something else.

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
select REPLACE('[ICCS]C54CNWHPEGNPY2V','[ICCS]','[ICCS] ') from dual;

select REPLACE(column_name,'[ICCS]','[ICCS] ') from table_name;
```

Suggested Update:

```
UPDATE dbo.KRM_CYCLE_DAY_ONE_DIFFERENCE KRM
   SET KRM.transaction_no =
          (REPLACE (KRM.TRANSACTION_NO, '[ICCS]', '[ICCS] '))
 WHERE EXISTS
          (SELECT 1
             FROM dbo.TEMP_CARD_NO T
            WHERE     KRM.transaction_no = '[ICCS]' || T.TRANSACTION_NO_NEW
                  AND SUBSTR (KRM.transaction_no, 1, 6) = '[ICCS]')
```

Comment: update KRM 
 set KRM.transaction_no = (REPLACE(KRM.TRANSACTION_NO,'[ICCS]','[ICCS] ') )
 From dbo.KRM_CYCLE_DAY_ONE_DIFFERENCE as KRM 
 inner join dbo.TEMP_CARD_NO as T
           on KRM.transaction_no = '[ICCS]'||T.TRANSACTION_NO_NEW 
 where substr(KRM.transaction_no,1,6)= '[ICCS]'       error   SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: You cannot use join directly on Update statements. 

You need to use exists in such cases. I have added a query in answer.. Try that and reply.

Comment: Oracle does not support ANSI 92 joins in UPDATE  (or DELETE for that matter). It would be neat if it did.